# Give the JavaScript the button's id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, this

In my JavaScript code, I have to make a line like this (I use smarty template engine, that is the literal stuff).

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxTextKill() {
        // ...etc.
        ajaxRequest.open("GET", "functions.php?action=kill{/literal}&id="+IWANTMYIDHERE+"&p={$smarty.get.page}&c={$smarty.get.sel}{literal}", true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null);
    }
```

After this in my HTML code,

```
<input type="button" id="87" value="del" onClick="return ajaxTextKill();" />
```

I'd like to give the JavaScript the input's id value. How to do this?

Comment: P.S.: ID's may not start with a number

Comment: You want id of the input button 87 in the place of IWANTMYIDHERE?

Comment: For your HTML to be valid, the `id` attribute **must** begin with a letter.  http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#h-6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the element pass itself to the function by `ajaxTextKill(this)`. Then just grab its ID by `element.id`.

```
function ajaxTextKill(element) {
    var buttonid = element.id;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "functions.php?action=kill{/literal}&id="+ buttonid +"&p={$smarty.get.page}&c={$smarty.get.sel}{literal}", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Indeed not in this construct. Fixed :)

Comment: No, it won't, because of the method used to handle the event.

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily need the ID if you pass a reference to the field itself.

```
<input type="button" id="87" value="del" onClick="return ajaxTextKill(this);" />
```

And access the ID like so:

```
function ajaxTextKill(object){
    alert(object.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="87" value="del" onClick="return ajaxTextKill(this.id);" />
```

The **JavaScript**

```
function ajaxTextKill(id){
...etc.
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "functions.php?action=kill{/literal}&id="+id+"&p={$smarty.get.page}&c={$smarty.get.sel}{literal}", true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" id="a87" value="del" onClick="return ajaxTextKill(this.id);" />
```